# A Radiant, Gradient Problem Find The Equation.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Determine whether or not the vector function
is a gradient. If so, find all the functions with that gradient.

$xy^2 i + x^2 y j$

What I first do is find the gradients for each problem thus finding the partial derivatives.

$\frac{∂f}{∂y}$ = $2yx$

$\frac{∂f}{∂x}$ = $ 2xy$

They are equal so we can say they are gradient.

Then we take

$\int\frac{∂f}{∂x}dx$ = $\frac{x^2}{2}$$y^2$ +$B(y)$

$\int\frac{∂f}{∂y}dy$ = $\frac{y^2}{2}$$x^2$ + $A(x)$

This is where I get lost in the problem I know the answer is $f(x,y)$ = $\frac{1}{2}x^2y^2 +C$ because the gradients are equal I feel that there is some step I missed for getting the final answer. Can anyone show me what that step is?

Comment: When you compute the indefinite integral with respect to, say, $x$, you also get a 'constant' that however depends on $y$, and vice versa. Thus, you actually have $x^2y^2/2+A(x) = x^2y^2/2+B(y)$, hence... I think that's what you feel is missing from the final step of your calculation.

Comment: I fixed the integrals, the constants were swapped: when you integrate with respect to $x$, you get a "constant" depending on $y$ and vice versa.

Comment: Also, strictly speaking, the partial derivatives being equal is only a necessary condition for the vector field to be a gradient of a function. For the field to be a gradient, you need it to be path-independent. Thus, you can say that the vector field is a gradient only after you've exhibited the anti-derivative, not before that.

Comment: Also, fixed vector field notations. You can't label both components as $f$, better $u$ and $v$ or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left out the "arbitrary constant" in your two integrals, and messed up on your notation. So a more complete answer is

$$f(x,y)=\frac 12x^2y^2+g(y)\quad\text{from integrating $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$: where $g(y)$ depends only on $y$}$$
$$f(x,y)=\frac 12x^2y^2+h(x)\quad\text{from integrating $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$: where $h(x)$ depends only on $x$}$$

Equating those two, you finally get

$$f(x,y)=\frac 12x^2y^2+C$$

where $C$ is a constant, independent of both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Kind of a dumb question but what does it mean when you say equating those two did you set them equal to each other?

Comment: @LittleJon: Yes, and subtracting $\frac 12x^2y^2$ from each side we get $g(y)=h(x)$, which can happen for all $x$ and $y$ in an interval only if both $g$ and $h$ are the same real constant. Do I need to justify that last statement?

Comment: No I  think I see what you mean you are left with g(y) = h(x) which means that they are equal to each other.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent confusion, I am posting this as a separate answer. It is important to understand that the condition $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ is in general only necessary but not sufficient for a field to be the gradient of a function, as shown by the standard example $\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}e_1-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}e_2$.

Using the naive method, you can compute two different "anti-derivatives" which won't agree everywhere, even though the respective partial derivatives agree.